# how to create incremental backup in GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.7.1-ee

Tags: command, backup, gitlab-ee, incremental

I want to create incremental backup from gitlab version 14.7.1
It is written in part of Git documentation that support is only possible in versions 14.9 and later.
how can i do ?

this commands not work:

sudo gitlab-backup create INCREMENTAL=yes PREVIOUS_BACKUP=<timestamp_of_backup>
sudo gitlab-backup create INCREMENTAL=yes BACKUP=<timestamp_of_backup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. GitLab should be updated to version 14.9.